# NullPointer Exception everytime I try to run my Junit Test Case

Tags: spring, junit, nullpointerexception

Every time i try to run the junit test case , i get null pointer exception and also when i tried to hadle the exception everytime the function returns NULL value. Here is the code.

**RestaurantRepository.java**

```
package org.springsource.restbucks;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Component
@Transactional
public interface RestaurantRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Restaurant, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Restaurant p Where (p.id)=(:Id) and p.deleted=false")
    Restaurant findById(@Param("Id") long Id);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Restaurant p Where LOWER(p.name)=LOWER(:name) and p.deleted = false")
    Restaurant findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

**RestaurantController.java**

```
@RestController
public class RestaurantController {
@Autowired
    RestaurantRepository repository;
@RequestMapping(value = "/restaurants/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Restaurant> getRestaurant(@PathVariable("id") long restaurantId) {
        Restaurant responseRestaurant = repository.findOne(restaurantId);
        if(responseRestaurant==null){
            logger.error("No Restaurant found with id:"+restaurantId);
            return new ResponseEntity<Restaurant>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }else if(responseRestaurant.isDeleted()==true){
            logger.error("Restaurant Object is deleted");
            return new ResponseEntity<Restaurant>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<Restaurant>(responseRestaurant,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

}
```

**RestaurantRepositoryTest.java**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class RestaurantRepositoryTest{

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantRepository repository;    

    @Test
    public void testfindById() throws Exception{ //testing findbyid method in restaurant repository

        Restaurant responseRestaurant = repository.findByName("xyz");   //getting error over here   
        assertEquals("xyz",responseRestaurant.getName());           
    }   
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception whenever i run **mvn test** . the stack trace is below what i get displayed in terminal.

- testfindById(org.springsource.restbucks.RestaurantRepositoryTest) 
  Time elapsed: 0.018 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.NullPointerException:
  null     at
- org.springsource.restbucks.RestaurantRepositoryTest.testfindById(RestaurantRepositoryTest.java:19)

what shall i do to run my test successfully??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running that as a pure unit test with no Spring context. Therefore, the repository will not be autowired. You should be able to fix that by adding a few annotations to the top of your test class.

If using Spring Boot, then something like the following should work, to let Spring Boot do all the hard work:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
```

You can alternatively load the Spring `@Configuration` class which would initialise your repositories (In my case, this is called `DbConfig`), like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DbConfig.class }, 
                      loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

Comment: This is an okay solution, but it unit test should not depend on the application context; it should test the controller in isolation. Injecting a mock repository is the way to go here.

Comment: i tried your way and the NULLPOINTER exception error is gone now ... !! now i have to figure out my way through this BEAN exception thing!!

Comment: Tip on that - Remove the `@Component` and `@Transactional` annotations from `RestaurantRepository`. Also the findById method should be taking a `Long` arg, not a `long`.

Comment: If you're using this to test the repository, you're doing an integration test. Those need to be done, but *after* isolated unit testing. (And only for customized methods; trusting Spring Data as much as possible is preferable to reinventing the wheel.)

Comment: SpringApplicationConfiguration  is "Deprecated as of 1.4 in favor of SpringBootTest or direct use of SpringBootContextLoader". "The search algorithm [of SpringBootTest] works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a \@SpringBootApplication or \@SpringBootConfiguration annotated class. As long as you’ve structured your code in a sensible way your main configuration is usually found." http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: Yep ... the new SpringBootTest annotation gives much better control over reducing what needs to be auto wired. Although you do sometimes end up having to mock quite a few beans. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your test is not starting up a Spring context at all, so the annotations are completely ignored. The best solution is to modify your controller class to take the repository as a constructor argument instead of using field injection. This allows you to pass in a simple mock, such as a Mockito mock, and avoid the complexity of starting up a Spring context to run a unit test.